# Unix Timestamp Chart.js with PHP echo

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js, unix-timestamp

I made a line chart with chart.js. For the values is some PHP script added. The axis only displayed the timestamp numbers. When I use a PHP function for timestamp conversion:

```
<?php echo date('H:i', $time); ?>
```

It totally crashes.

This is my code for the PHP time echo. How can I display `HH:ii` on my X axis of the chart?

```
<?php  

    $total = (count($data)) - 1;

    if ($total > 100) {
      $start = $total - 100;
      $end = $total;
    } 
    else {
      $start = 0;
      $end = $total;
    }

    for ($x = $start; $x < $end; $x++) {
       if ($x % 5  == 0) {
         //echo $x; //5th element
         $row = $data[$x];
         $time = intval($row->{'time'});
         echo $time;
       } else{
         echo ' '; //prints empty for other than 5th element
       }

       echo ', '; //prints ',' for every element
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with:

```
echo '\'' . date('H:i', $time) . '\'';
```